# What are the base stats for each tower per upgrade level?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Although I primarily play an apprentice, I will be experimenting with the other classes. Therefore, **I am interested in knowing the health, attack speed, damage, and range for every tower and for all upgrade levels of the towers.** For towers that do not deal damage, knowing their health levels and the degree to which their other effects scale per tower level would be sufficient.

Edit: I am interested in the base stats, not stats for all possible builds. If you want to tack on how the stats affect each tower, however (such as: +.5 damage per point in tower damage), that would be a nice touch!

Comment: seeing how towers are affected by the character's stats that'll be one huge table

Comment: @yx: I'm interested in the base stats, not the stats based on your character build.

Comment: @Shaun These may end up changing with patches as well. We've already had a DPS scale increase for Monks and decrease for Squires.

Comment: @Shaun I started working on an answer for your question, but given how narrow the answer column is on the site, it's made it so you have to scroll to the side pretty far to get all of the info. :/ I'm pondering just taking pics of the Wikia tables (where I'm getting my info) instead because it's neater, but the problem I see with that is updating the tables later on after patches, which leaves deprecated images just sitting on the server. Which would you prefer?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I think the text-based method would work best. If you do a different table per tower, a different row per level, and the columns represent stats, it would likely be more managable. Alternatively, you could make a public Google Spreadsheet and link it here.

Comment: @Shaun Even with a different table per tower, it scrolls off the edge for each tower. :/ A Google Spreadsheet would be a bit easier to put together, but that kind of goes against having all the information on the SE site itself. I'll work on finishing up the individual tables first and see how that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I spent over an hour trying to convert these tables into something readable for the format here, but frankly, I think it's best if you check out the information on the [Dungeon Defenders Wikia Wiki itself](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_Defenders_Wiki), specifically the [Tower](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Towers) articles. The conversion I attempted to do to fit the format here was ugly and less handy to look at and scroll through. In addition, when these values change due to patches, I likely would've been referencing the wiki anyway for the value changes, so it seems best to point you to the primary source.

For instance, if you go to the [Gas Trap article](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Gas_Trap), you can find all the statistics you are looking for in the table, like Number of Activations, Defense Units, Effective Range, Effective Duration, Activation Range, Detonation Reset Time, and Mana to Upgrade. There are links at the bottom of that article for every single class tower with all the information you are looking for!

Comment: Aye, in this case, linking to the external resource was probably the best bet. :)